# Is height along the x-axis and width along the y-axis in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Shouldn't this convention be in reverse?

Desktop app config

```
cfg.width = 454;
cfg.height = 756;
```

//Logcat also shows what's expected

```
Gdx.app.log("height",Integer.toString(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));.//756
Gdx.app.log("width",Integer.toString(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));//454
```

but then this:

```
shapeRenderer.line(40, 400, 700, 400);
```

produces this line:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default no. LIBGDX uses OpenGL's default origin in the bottom left corner, with Y going up and X going right.

Your camera could be messed up.

Looks like you're running this on Mac. You using RoboVM or Mono?  RoboVM support is very new. Its possible there's some bug.

Comment: I commented out a line  - it fixed the problem ...shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);